# Solutions to $\left\lvert 1-e^{ia} \right\rvert= \left\lvert 1-e^{ib} \right\rvert$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I am looking for the Solutions to the equation 
$\left\lvert 1-e^{ia} \right\rvert= \left\lvert 1-e^{ib} \right\rvert$
for $a,b \ge 0.$

Wolframalpha suggests that the Solutions are $a=b+2\pi \mathbb{Z},$ i.e. we only have the trivial ones. However, I could not find a proof of this by myself. Does anybody have an idea how to Show this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square both sides, use that $\lvert z \rvert^2 = z^*z$, so
$$ \lvert 1-e^{ia} \rvert^2 = (1-e^{-ia})(1-e^{ia}) = 1-e^{ia}-e^{-ia}+1=2 - (e^{ia} + e^{-ia}) = 2-2\cos{a}. $$
Similarly, the right-hand sides is $2-2\cos{b}$, so we want
$$ \cos{a}-\cos{b}=0. $$
You can now solve this easily using one of the prosthaphaeresis formulae to write this as a product of sines.

Comment: $|z|^2 = \bar{z} * z$

Comment: @Ahmed Chappers isn't using the $*$ for multiplication. He is using a different notation for complex conjugate, $z^{*} = \bar{z}$.